# Restrict some site features for members

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, cookies

I'm developing a site that has a set of core features available to everyone, as well as a set of special features reserved for members of the site. For instance, all users will be able to view a post but only members will be able to include tags, share the post, etc. As far as html output, the extra features would only result in a few extra icons within the post. What I'm looking for is guidance on the best way to reserve features for members. For instance, two options I've been considering are:

**Method 1**

 1. Creating a version of the site for non-members and a version for members. The version for members would include the entire non-member site plus the additional code (html, css, js, etc) required to implement the extra features. Cookies and/or sessions would then be used to check the status of the user and redirect them to the correct version of the site.

**Method 2**

 2. Having one version. The extra features (i.e. the few extra icons) would be hidden by default and become visible only when the user is logged in. (This would presumably take some js, which I'm not worried about users disabling).

Searches for this type of problem returned a bunch of solutions regarding user admin levels, permissions and wordpress plugins. None of these really apply so if you have any other ideas, awesome! If not, I'd really appreciate your feedback on the methods listed above. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this with `php` and `session`. You already have your answer...

Comment: @rjdown If i'm not mistaken, both of the considerations I've listed can be implemented with php/session. That alone doesn't really help me decide which one is the better solution.

Comment: Make one site, and hide and show when user is logged in and has a certain role assigned to them (admin/not admin). In point 2) you presume wrong. You can show and hide features using sessions in php. Javascript is sort of icing on the cake but not a driving force for concealing extra functions and visuals to different user groups.

Comment: @Rasclatt Thanks! I had yet to come across showing and hiding features with php. I appreciate the clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to illustrate, on your `index.php` page, or whatever page, for testing, paste this code at the very top and use the links to toggle between sessions:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<a href="?admin=1">Admin User</a>
<a href="?admin=0">Not Admin</a>
<a href="?admin=base">Not logged in</a>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['admin']) && $_GET['admin'] == 1)
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
elseif(isset($_GET['admin']) && $_GET['admin'] == 0)
    $_SESSION['admin'] = false;

if(isset($_GET['admin']) && $_GET['admin'] == 'base')
      if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) unset($_SESSION['admin']);

if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == true) { ?>
    <p>You are admin and this is your image</p>
    <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/african-tree-frog.jpg" />
<?php } elseif(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == false) { ?>
    <p>You are NOT admin but logged in. This is your image.</p>
    <img src="http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/10/images/051007_robot_fish.jpg" />
<?php }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) { ?>
    <h2>You are not logged in!</h2>
    <?php } ?>

<p>This is a site about animals. Everyone can read this.</p>
<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great starting point to build what I needed.